# Find All Cells Containing string and Copy Adjacent

Tags: excel, vba, search, find

I am trying to search for all cells containing a specific string value. If possible multiple strings e.g.

> "*Text*Text*" that would find "123Text123Text123"

within a given range and return an ID reference from that row.

I managed to use an "If Cell.Value = xxx" scenario however this only looks for exact matches rather than **containing**:

```
intMyVal = InputBox("Please enter Sales Order No.")
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
newrow = 1
For Each Cell In Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow) 'Data to search
    If Cell.Value = intMyVal Then
        Cells(Cell.Row, 1).Copy 'Copy ID1 value
        Sheets("TempData").Cells(newrow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste ID1 value in temp data
        newrow = newrow + 1
    End If
Next Cell
```

The below images shows an extract of the data.  Column D would be searched for specific text strings (e.g. "Tesco" or "Ireland") and for each hit, the corresponding value in column A would be copied to a temporary data page.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than look at each cell use `FIND` and `FINDNEXT`:

```
Public Sub FindSales()

    Dim sValToFind As String
    Dim rSearchRange As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rFoundCell As Range
    Dim rAllFoundCells As Range
    Dim sMessage As String

    sValToFind = InputBox("Please enter Sales Order No.")
    'Code to check a valid number entered
    '.
    '.

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With rSearchRange
         Set rFoundCell = .Find(sValToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
         If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAdd = rFoundCell.Address
            Do

                sMessage = sMessage & rFoundCell.Row & ", "

                'Create a range of found cells.
                If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, rFoundCell)
                Else
                    Set rAllFoundCells = rFoundCell
                End If
                Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)
            Loop While rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAdd
         End If
    End With

    rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    sMessage = sValToFind & " found on rows " & Mid(sMessage, 1, Len(sMessage) - 2) & "."
    MsgBox sMessage, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks.  I have modified slightly as the values I need to copy are in different column to the lookup.

`Set temp_dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempData")
     rAllFoundCells.Offset(, -3).Copy
    temp_dest.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues'`

Comment: One issue I am now having with this is when I am broadening the search to various columns.  The offset method I used above only works when I know the column that the data would be found in.  Can you suggest a tweak that would allow me to always copy the data from column A for each row of data that returns a positive find?  Thanks, Dan

Comment: You could add new `Range` variable, I've called it `rColA`.  In the line above the `Create a range of found cells` comment add this code:  Set `rColA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rFoundCell.Row, 1)`.  This will return a reference to column A on the found row.  Then on the two `Set rAllFoundCells....` lines change `rFoundCell` to `rColA`.  You can then change `rSearchRange` to any column and it will always return the values in column A for the found rows.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple: use `Like` operator: `If someCell.Value Like "*Text*Text*" Then` would do exactly what you want.

In your case I suppose it would be:

```
If Cell.Value Like "*" & intMyVal & "*" Then
```